# Remove strong tag in a text-file with sed

Tags: html, sed, text-files

I want to remove the `STRONG` tags in a text-file.

I'm using `sed 's/< strong>/>/g'` for removing the `STRONG` tag and that works fine.

But when I want to remove the `< /STRONG>` tag with this `sed 's/< /strong>//g'` 
it states the following error `sed: -e expression #1, char 13: Unknown option to`s'`

I believe it has to do with the `< /`-part but I don't know what. Can somebody please explain me how to fix it?

**The space between `<` and `strong` and others is on purpose for this question-only**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `/` as a pattern/replacement separator, if you want to match/replace one (`/`), you must escape it (like: `\/`) that way, but more on that see below.

sed is not an ideal tool for (X|HT)ML processing. If the tag does not span to multiple lines, it might work for you:

```
sed 's_</\s*\?strong>_>_g' INPUTFILE
```

This replaces both `<strong>`, `< strong>`, `</strong>`, `< /strong>` with a single `>` (as you had written in the question). `sed` can use several pattern/replacement separators, not just `/` (I'm using `_` above.)

Comment: Perhaps something got lost in translation? is `'s_<\s*/\?\s*strong>_>_g'` what you meant?

Comment: Both answers did not work @ Zsolt: <strong> still remains and </strong> is rpelaced by >. @ potong your answer replaced <strong> and also </strong> by >

Comment: I replaced the separator > with | and that did the trick. Here the solution for others with this problem: sed 's|</strong>||g' prut6.xml > prut7.xml  Zsolt and Potong thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the separator `>` with `|` and that did the trick. Here the solution for others with this problem:

```
sed 's|</strong>||g' prut6.xml > prut7.xml
```

Zsolt and Potong, thanks!